# How to melt `pandas.DataFrame` with hour columns and divide them on 15 minutes intervals

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, melt

I have a `DataFrame` something like this:

```py
data = [['2019-01-01', .1, .2],
        ['2019-01-02', .5, .3],
        ['2019-01-03', .2, .4]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['date', 'hour01', 'hour02'])
```

```
         date  hour01  hour02
0  2019-01-01     0.1     0.2
1  2019-01-02     0.5     0.3
2  2019-01-03     0.2     0.4
```

How to melt it so that I get proper 15 minutes intervals? Like this:

```
    timestamp              value
0  2019-01-01 00:00:00     0.1
1  2019-01-01 00:15:00     0.1
2  2019-01-01 00:30:00     0.1
3  2019-01-01 00:45:00     0.1
4  2019-01-01 01:00:00     0.2
5  2019-01-01 01:15:00     0.2
6  2019-01-01 01:30:00     0.2
7  2019-01-01 01:45:00     0.2
...
16 2019-01-03 00:00:00     0.2
17 2019-01-03 00:15:00     0.2
18 2019-01-03 00:30:00     0.2
19 2019-01-03 00:45:00     0.2
20 2019-01-03 01:00:00     0.4
21 2019-01-03 01:15:00     0.4
22 2019-01-03 01:30:00     0.4
23 2019-01-03 01:45:00     0.4
```

#### Edit

```py
df.melt(id_vars=['timestamp'], value_vars=['hour_{}'.format(str(x).zfill(2)) for x in range(1, 24)])
```

gives me this:

```
27    2017-01-28  hour_01  34.90
28    2017-01-29  hour_01  36.04
29    2017-01-30  hour_01  36.51
          ...      ...    ...
16760 2018-12-02  hour_23  51.50
16761 2018-12-03  hour_23  54.00
16762 2018-12-04  hour_23  53.87
```

Where to go from here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution based on `melt`, `set_index`  and `ffill`:

```
df = df.melt(id_vars=['date'], var_name='hour')
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date']) + pd.to_timedelta(df['hour'].str[4:].astype(int) - 1, unit='h')
df = df.set_index(pd.DatetimeIndex(df['timestamp']))
df = df.drop(columns=['timestamp', 'date', 'hour'])
df = df.resample('15T').ffill()
df = df.reset_index()
```

Results:

```
              timestamp  value
0   2019-01-01 00:00:00    0.1
1   2019-01-01 00:15:00    0.1
2   2019-01-01 00:30:00    0.1
3   2019-01-01 00:45:00    0.1
4   2019-01-01 01:00:00    0.2
..                  ...    ...
192 2019-01-03 00:00:00    0.2
193 2019-01-03 00:15:00    0.2
194 2019-01-03 00:30:00    0.2
195 2019-01-03 00:45:00    0.2
196 2019-01-03 01:00:00    0.4
```

Answer (score 5):

Maybe you can do it starting with `melt` too, but unless using `melt` is by some reason a requirement, you can obtain it in this way:

1. Make `'date'` a `datetime` column, if not already.
2. Using `groupby` and `apply` you can generate the timestamps for all the time intervals using [pandas date_range](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html) and spanning the hourly values using [numpy repeat](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html).
3. Finally reset the index.

Translated in a code is:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

ddf = df.groupby('date').apply(lambda row : pd.DataFrame(
      {'timestamp' : pd.date_range(row['date'].iloc[0], periods=4*len(df.columns[1:]), freq='15T'),
       'value' : np.repeat(np.array([row[col].iloc[0] for col in df.columns[1:]]), 4)}))
ddf.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)
```

Using your starting dataframe, `ddf` is:

```
             timestamp  value
0  2019-01-01 00:00:00    0.1
1  2019-01-01 00:15:00    0.1
2  2019-01-01 00:30:00    0.1
3  2019-01-01 00:45:00    0.1
4  2019-01-01 01:00:00    0.2
5  2019-01-01 01:15:00    0.2
6  2019-01-01 01:30:00    0.2
7  2019-01-01 01:45:00    0.2
8  2019-01-02 00:00:00    0.5
9  2019-01-02 00:15:00    0.5
10 2019-01-02 00:30:00    0.5
11 2019-01-02 00:45:00    0.5
12 2019-01-02 01:00:00    0.3
13 2019-01-02 01:15:00    0.3
14 2019-01-02 01:30:00    0.3
15 2019-01-02 01:45:00    0.3
16 2019-01-03 00:00:00    0.2
17 2019-01-03 00:15:00    0.2
18 2019-01-03 00:30:00    0.2
19 2019-01-03 00:45:00    0.2
20 2019-01-03 01:00:00    0.4
21 2019-01-03 01:15:00    0.4
22 2019-01-03 01:30:00    0.4
23 2019-01-03 01:45:00    0.4
```

This code will automatically pick how many columns you have after `'date'`, assuming that they are all `'hour'` columns. If you have other columns mixed in the dataframe, they should be filtered out from `df.columns[1:]`.